# What Docker Image to chose for MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, docker

What docker image should I use to host a MVC .NET (NOT CORE!) application? I need to host a solution with five separate projects, which will integrate into hosted TFS build agent.

I've looked around on various posts and certain posts suggest microsoft/windowsserveriis, others microsoft/aspnet.

Which one is correct?

**NOTE:** it will not be hosted in the cloud, if that matters.

**EDIT 1:**

After searching for nearly an hour I've found this video that seems to explain it a bit better:

[Docker for .NET Developers](https://youtu.be/a8Z3MncihLg?t=353). Basically it seems as if **microsoft/aspnet** inherits from **microsoft/iis**

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#prerequisites 
Try  this.

Comment: @Manusha not sure how much that helps as it's a .net core example. It gets a lot more convoluted with .bet core, especially legacy applications such as this...